# Typescript is unable to predict possible types for a variable indexed in an array

Tags: typescript

**Example:**

```
var x: (string | null) [] =  [];

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    x.push(prompt('Enter some string of click "cancel" to input "null"'));
}

function check(stringOnly: string){
    console.log(stringOnly, " is a string");
}

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    check(x[i]);
}
```

The above code shows

1. An array of items where each item will either be a **string** or **null**
2. And then a loop that fills this array with 3 unpredictable **(string | null)** values
3. A function that accepts a **string** parameter and only **string** (no **null** allowed)
4. And finally a loop that attempts to pass each item in the array to that function.

Now, typescript reasonably complains at the line in the last loop saying:

> Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Until now, that makes sense! But then I edit the code adding a condition to verify that the item is a string before passing it to the `chech()` function, so the code becomes

```
var x: (string | null) [] =  [];

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    x.push(prompt('Enter some string of click "cancel" to input "null"'));
}

function check(stringOnly: string){
    console.log(stringOnly, " is a string");
}

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(x[i])
       check(x[i]);
}
```

This would usually fix the problem but it looks like this time it didn't and typescript is still unable to verify that this operation is allowed. Because x[i] is not only a variable of unpredictable value, it's not only **x** that typescript cannot predict but also **i** and it still assumes that `x[i]` can still be null even inside the if condition: `if(x[i])`, `if(x[i] !== null)` or even `if(typeof(x[i]) === 'string')`

So what is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: It's because you're using `x[i]`, TS can't narrow the whole array type; compare to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAHgXBAUBnALmAlgOwOYQD4QwFcAbYgSggG0BdCAXgiuoG4BYAKA4DMB7MeUJDR0ADMwhoAPAGZxaANTyyAbw6NGUAHQAHQogAW8bWB4BbbcngByAKIZkAU0iIzDiCnTYIPLhADGxGh+ANYQAER+IBh+DsRhEMg8Ehi6yOFEpGFWZGRs7AC+HNyE0choPBj++g4hSKiYWADyGMQAnnAeDSpq6n4VLsQOmsQ8WHWeTS2tADThEogQIO712GG5HIWc7Lz8ghKicjJyit3s6v79aY7m9NCUaCw9jGhc8NfaZE-nftW17+sFIA. You could [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) `check(x[i] as string)` to narrow it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asserts to do this, but depending on the needs of your code, you may find it useful to have a generic typeguard-for-array type function (I know I've found this kind of thing useful in the past):

```
var x: (string | null) [] =  [];

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    x.push(prompt('Enter some string of click "cancel" to input "null"'));
}

function check(stringOnly: string){
    console.log(stringOnly, " is a string");
}

function guardArray<T>(xs: any[], guard: (x: any) => x is T) {
    return xs.filter(guard);
}

const isString = (x: any): x is string => typeof x === 'string';

guardArray(x, isString)
    .forEach(check);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBAHgXBAUBnALmAlgOwOYQD4QwFcAbYgSggG0BdCAXgiuoG4BYAKA4DMB7MeUJDR0ADMwhoAPAGZxaANTyyAbw6NGUAHQAHQogAW8bWB4BbbcngByAKIZkAU0iIzDiCnTYIPLhADGxGh+ANYQAER+IBh+DsRhEMg8Ehi6yOFEpGFWZGRs7AC+HNyE0choPBj++g4hSKiYWADyGMQAnnAeDSpq6n4VLsQOmsQ8WHWeTS2tADThEogQIO712GG5HIWc7FwlfmUVEFiE4AAmAIJgYCCtkgAqAHzwUIhwUa00s0encE+vGK0UOj3aDzCC3CiqdjqCBgBzIQhgSrPTRcNDERz8L5gE7rApFdh9DAoeYAZRWOAYv0W-zIcCgoM6XiBCVa2gcPhBdC5ECsjKwVjyHCx50u1yeszQiDJEzIPUYKL4NhAfkMKpqwVyQA)

This way you ensure that the type of your array is as type-secure as your guard.